# How I can do this solution faster? c++

Tags: c++, алгоритм

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
unsigned long long r, t, k, s;
cin >> r >> t >> k;
s = r * 3 + t * 2;
if (s < k){
    cout << s;
}
else{
    while(s >= k){
        s -= k;
    }
    cout << s;
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, если вы хотите этого...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    unsigned long long r, t, k;
    cin >> r >> t >> k;
    cout << (r * 3 + t * 2)%k;
}
```